# Faster way of finding critical points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

So I am looking at parametric vector function. 
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        \cos (t) & -\sin (t) & 0 \\
        \cos f(t) \sin (t) & \cos f(t) \cos (t) & -\sin f(t) \\
        \sin f(t) \sin (t) & \sin f(t) \cos (t) & \cos f(t) \\
        \end{vmatrix}
\cdot
 \begin{vmatrix}
        X_1 + u(X_2 - X_1) \\
        Y_1 + u(Y_2 - Y_1) \\
        Z_1 + u(Z_2 - Z_1) \\
        \end{vmatrix}
=
\vec v(t)
$$

where

$$ u = \frac{t-\lambda_1}{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}$$

for $ 0^\circ \le t \lt 180^\circ$

Is there any way of knowing max and min values for each axis without differentiating and solving for x' = 0, y' = 0, and z' = 0? The problem with this approach is that I am trying to do these calculations through programming (and kind of quickly). The only thing I can think of is loop through your range (0-180) and see where your result is closest to 0. 1st issue: this is an approximation. 2nd issue: This is a lot of processing power. I wouldn't care so much that it is an approximation if I could come up with it fast, but I can't. Any ideas on a faster method or alternative approaches would be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect that, if properly implemented, the direct solve after differentiation might be quicker than the loop-and-sample algorithm, especially since you'll need to polish any approximate solution (mos' likely).  It seems to me the trick will be to solve as far as you can algebraically before coding.  Best of luck with this.  Cheers.

Comment: I tried to do this (at least with arc length), but it gets very hairy. Squaring the derivative of my x-function gives me an expression with like 20 different terms that I could not find a nice way of combining.

Comment: Hmmm . . . thinking about it.  Are the $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$ constants?

Comment: If you are talking about $X_1 , Y_1 , Z_1 , X_2 , Y_2, Z_2$ then yes.

Comment: OK, thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: One more thing.  When you write "max and min values for each axis" do you mean the extrema of the components of $\vec v(t)$, so for the $x$-axis we would be looking at $v_x$ where $\vec v = (v_x, v _y, v_z)^T$?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: OK, thanks for the speedy responses . . . thinking . . . will let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: awesome, any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: Why then do you need to look at the square of anything?  My first intuition is to simply extremize $v_x$, etc., no need to square . . .

Comment: Sorry, that was for solving the arc length, but I have been working on just solving x' = 0, and it is still very hairy. Because of the 't' term in our 'u', you have to use the product rule, and I can't solve for 0.

Comment: I see the complications . . . still thinking . . . Cheers!